# Storing current url in database table dynamically in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, dreamweaver

I am a **novice** with website designing and I am currently working on a quiz game website with each level on a seperate page.

I would like to explain my question with an example:-

A user logs in (by validating username and password from database ofcourse) and redirected to page 1 (question 1) answered correctly and then redirected to page 2 (question 2). Now he closes his browser and everything and after 3-4 hours logs in again.

**Main problem --> Now i want him to be directly redirected to page 2 ( the page he was on in his last visit)**

What am i supposed to do for this purpose ? Should i use **$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']** and store it in database to use it when the user logs in again?

**:::I am using dreamweaver cc and wamp as local server.**

Comment: personally, I would create a db table that stores `userID, quizID, quizPageID`. Then when they are redirected to page 2, etc., you insert a row with those values. If a user row does not exist, then start them at page 1.

Comment: Modern PHP development encourages the use of a [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/)  that gives you a solid foundation for building your application. Find one that suits your style and needs and follow the examples and documentation. Most have a large library of community code you can add in with little effort, avoiding the need to reinvent the wheel. Using one of these it's trivial to add a database, add user accounts, and capture their results.

Comment: Unfortunately, this question requires a pretty broad and length answer, one that will not come easy on SO without some examples of what you've tried. A lot of this depends on the structure of your site. For certain though, you'll want to store the progress in a database. The next time the user logs in, use the progress indicator to redirect to the proper page (i.e. if the user is on question 2 redirect to http://examplequizgame.com/question/2). Obviously this depends on a lot of factors including your design structure and URL structure.

Comment: Yeah, i think that would be the simplest one to follow  :-)  thanks @Sean

Comment: @3Demon This kind of application is a great "getting-started" example. Even if you're unfamiliar with a framework like Laravel, it would only take a few days to get up and running if you follow their examples and use the framework's conventions.